# Choose a different simulator in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

How to choose a different simulator(other than iOS 8) in Xcode 6?. I have successfully installed the iOS 7 simulator from ***Xcode->Preference->Downloads***

[image]

But it is not listing in the available simulators for running

[image]

Any one know how can i install iOS7 simulator in Xcode 6?

Comment: try quit the xcode and restart again , quit means kill xcode..not minimize..

Comment: Quit and relaunched several times. still no use

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once installed iOS 7 simulator, in Xcode 6 go **Window** > **Devices**, click on bottom left corner **+** button and add iOS 7 simulator. Then you can choose it in your *Archive Scheme*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure your deployment target is set to at least <= 7.0 or else you'll only see the iOS 8 simulators